# How to set pageCount manually in vuejs-paginate?

Tags: vue.js, pagination

My HTML:

```
<paginate
        :pageCount="max"
        :containerClass="'pagination'"
        :clickHandler="redirectToPage"
        :force-page="selectedPage">
</paginate>
```

**max** is getter from *vuex*. When paginate is loading max = undefined, so I need to set **pageCount** after value max is changed.

In offical docs only static value:
[image]

Comment: maybe `v-if="max"`?

Comment: It didn`t help.

Comment: You can't use props in this way you set them.They should be kebab-case - `page-count` , `container-class`, `click-handler`

Comment: I try with kebab-case style, nothing changed :(

Comment: Could you try create computed property, and return that max getter there, and check would any change would be applied ?

Comment: Did as you said, but any changes

Comment: Well then probably is something wrong with the getter in vuex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking **Belmin Bedak**'s comment into account, here it is working with a `v-if` to make it wait for `pageCount` to load. In testing, I found that updating `pageCount` works as expected: the number of pages available is updated.

```js
vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    max: null
  },
  components: {
    paginate: VuejsPaginate
  },
  methods: {
    clickCallback: function(page) {
      console.log(page);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // Pretend we're getting from vuex
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.max = 7;
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuejs-paginate@0.8.0"></script>
<div id="app">
    <paginate v-if="max"
      :page-count="max"
      :container-class="'pagination'"
      :click-handler="clickCallback">
    </paginate>
    <div v-else>
    Loading...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52363283/how-to-display-content-by-page-number-or-prev-next-clicked-on-the-vue